# How to Stop the Apt Methods Driver

Tags: apt

16.04
It seems that no matter what I do, I get the methods/http doing a download of 3mb.  I want to control updates so it only gets the cache when I do

```
sudo apt update
```

It seems like I am the only one who cares about this.

There is a similar question about eating bandwidth [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwic5YSt9KXSAhULxGMKHY4jDZcQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Faskubuntu.com%2Fquestions%2F33530%2Fusr-lib-apt-methods-http-eating-my-bandwidth&usg=AFQjCNGb5PrrCCg2JV7qMPs_IcvP1XQqIQ&sig2=l0ZtuzwpoKrq8SXnKs4rzA)..
but that does not offer a solution.. It only slows it down.

I tried the command line listed below also, but it still did not work.

```
sudo systemctl disable apt-daily.service 
sudo systemctl disable apt-daily.timer
```

Here is a picture of my update screen
[image]

Comment: Next time you see that process, run `pstree -psa <PID>` with its PID to see what started it.

Comment: It runs everytime at startup.  It seems so crazy that I am the only one that wants "never check" to really be never check.  It costs money to load 3mb every time I boot.  I am now suspending more often to prevent this mb attack.